# an std:map deletion causing the program to halt indefinitely

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, dictionary

I wrote a solution to some Project Euler problem. My algorithm works, outputs the solution, but never terminates.

Here is the program (compiled under MS VS2013):

```
using bigint = __int64;
using cache = std::map<bigint, int>;

auto collatz_length(bigint n, cache* memory)->int
{
        if (memory->empty()) {
                memory->emplace(1, 1);
        }

        auto search_result = decltype(memory->end()){};

        if ((search_result = memory->find(n)) != memory->end()) {
                return search_result->second;
        }

        auto next = n;
        auto length = 0;


        do {
                next = next % 2 == 0 ?
                        next / 2 :
                        next * 3 + 1;
                length++;
        } while (next > n);

        auto result = length + collatz_length(next, memory);

        memory->emplace(n, result);
        return result;
}


auto project_eulerXXX()->void
{
        auto 
                max = 1000 * 1000,
                longest = 0,
                current = -1,
                argmax = 1;
        auto memo = new cache();

        for (auto i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
                if ((current = collatz_length(i, memo)) > longest) {
                        longest = current;
                        argmax = i;
                }
        }
        std::cout << "max for i = 1 to " << max << " is for " << argmax << std::endl;

        delete memo;
}

auto _tmain()->int
{
        project_eulerXXX();


        std::cout << "done!\n";
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

The message `done!` is never written on the console. But the function `project_eulerXXX()` outputs the solution. I believe that the function is stucked somewhere around the delete (when I break, the debugger confirms that the function `project_eulerXXX()` did not terminate).

Note that

- the issue remains when an `unique_prt` owns the `std::map`
- the issue disappears when I comment the line with the delete

What is the matter with my program?

Comment: But why do you use new and delete in the first place? That's so clumsy.

Comment: Why are you even allocating things on the heap here?  You could just as easily do `cache memo;` and then the object will be automatically destroyed when its scope ends. `new`/`delete` has no benefit here, and several drawbacks.

Comment: Yeah, all this C++11 show off with plenty of `auto`s and then new/delete inside a function, and using raw pointers instead of references? Confused...

Comment: `auto search_result = decltype(memory->end()){};` That's a seriously weird line. How about `auto search_result = memory->find(n); if (search_result != memory->end() { ...`?

Comment: @cdhowie yes, I know. It s just to get familiar with the standard library; the issue is not about the way to get to the solution (anyway, a `vector<int>` is probably more appropriate here).

Comment: What happens if instead of `std::cout << "done!\n";` you do `std::cout << "done!" << std::endl;`? It's possible that the output stream just isn't being flushed (`std::endl` will flush it), and you're hanging in `std::cin.get()` waiting for input.

Comment: @SebastianRedl this is because I use `search_result` next line.

Comment: @cdhowie it does not work. and it does not explain why the program terminates when I comment the `delete` line.

Comment: @mookid What happens if you use a stack-allocated map like I suggested? (`cache memo;`)

Comment: I tried your very code with VS2013 and it prints "done". I hit enter and the process is gone.

Comment: @cdhowie with `cache memo ..... (current = collatz_length(i, &memo)` it does not work either.

Comment: After adding the necessary `include`s and changes to make it compile with gcc, I can confirm, that it prints *done* and terminates successfully.

Comment: Actually I removed that horrific __int64 thing and added a few includes, but it works on VS2013 almost exactly as it is, with the delete in place.

Comment: @gd1 thanks for running it. This is strange; I restarted visual studio, recompiled it and both in debug and release modes, I still does not end. And in the task manager, the memory used by the program does not decrease after the output (it is around 150Mo and stays at this level).

Comment: That's so odd. And it doesn't print "done!" does it?

Comment: @gd1 no, it does not.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll test it on another machine and VS installation if you like, but that's so odd.

Comment: thanks you all for your time.